# Content Type Publishing error

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-server, content-type-hub

We have a SharePoint 2010 environment with multiple site collections in it.

We created a content type in the root site and published it to all the site collections.
It got replicated everywhere. Now, in one particular site collection called Data, we made some changes to the content type and columns attached to the content type. Then we deleted the entire content type in the Data Site collection.

Now, if we publish the content type again from the root site, it is not getting mapped to the Data workstream.

When I checked the publishing error logs, it says:

> Field internal name 'DataObject' conflict

Please let us overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like when you deleted the content type you didn't actually delete the columns related to the content type.  Now you are trying to publish a content type from the root with that 'DataObject' column in it but there already exists a 'DataObject' column in your site collection.

Have you searched your site columns to ensure that you don't already have a 'DataObject' column there?

Updated:
Here is some powershell you can run to check for the column in question either in content types or in lists.  Also make sure the primary and second stage recycle bins are empty of any documents that could have been tagged with that CT.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://{servername}
$str = 'DataObject'

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach ($ct in $web.ContentTypes)
    {
        foreach ($field in $ct.Fields) {
            if($field.InternalName.Contains($str))  {
              Write-Host "'$web' web - Found a match in the '$ct' content type"
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        foreach ($field in $list.Fields) {
          if($field.InternalName.Contains($str))  {
            Write-Host "'$web' web - Found a match in the '$field' field in the '$list' list"
          }
        }
    }
$web.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We added 6 columns to the content type. There were few other default columns which exist when we create a content type. We are sure that there are no columns (6 which we created) existing in the site content type and we have verified it as well. Kindly let us overcome this error as this takes such a long time to identify and resolve. Thanks.

Comment: Here is some powershell you can run on your site to find the column either in a content type or list.  Also make sure your recycle bins (both primary and second-stage) are empty of any documents that may have used the content type.